# How to iterate a file filled with file and directory paths to check what they are

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I have a problem which is iterating a file called for example: fileAndFolderPaths, and in other script I have to iterate this same file and check if each line is a file or folder path.

fileAndFolderPaths

```
/opt/sampleFolder
/opt/sampleFolder/aText.txt
/opt/otherFolder
```

Then my script file is something like that:

myScript.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

mapfile -t array < /tmp/fileAndFolderPaths

function checkIfFilesOrFolder(){

for i in "${array[@]}" do
   if [ -f $i ]; then
     echo -e "[Info] found the file: $i"
   elif [ -d $i ]; then
     echo -e "[Info] found the directory: $i"
   else
     echo -e "[Error] Nor directory or file were found based on this value: $i"
   fi
done
}

checkIfFilesOrFolder

exit 0;
```

The problem is the check only works for the last line of the array created by the mapfile command. Any thoughts about that? I'm new to shell scripting so probably this is a really basic problem, but even so I wasn't able to fix it yet.

Comment: you're missing a semicolon between `for i in "${array[@]}"` and `do` ... is that a typo or it really missing from your code?  I added the semicolon and the program worked for me; please update the question with the output from `typeset -p array` (this will show us the exact contents of the array)

Comment: Get in the habit of checking your code htttps://shellcheck.net . Be sure to include the correct first line, i.e. `#!/bin/bash` would be typical. Good luck.

Comment: Run your script with `bash -x myScript.sh` and examine the trace output: it might give a clue. Also, you can dump the contents of a variable with `declare -p array` to inspect it.

Comment: (optional) Consider `[ -s "$i" ]` to check both if the file exists and is non-empty. **Always** quote your variables in `[ ... ]`, or use `[[ .. ]]`.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of review suggestions, if you don't mind:

1. Don't need the global variable: pass the filename to the function and loop over the file:

   ```sh
   checkIfFilesOrFolder() {
       local file=$1
       while IFS= read -r line; do
           # test "$line" here ...
       done < "$file"
   }

   checkIfFilesOrFolder /tmp/fileAndFolderPaths
   ```

   I recommend using `local` for function variables, to minimize polluting the global namespace.
2. Always quote your variables, unless you're aware of exactly what expansions occur on them unqoted:

   ```sh
   if [ -f "$line" ]; then ...
   ```
3. is there a reason you're using `echo -e`? The common advice is to use

   ```sh
   printf '[Info] found the file: %s\n' "$line"
   ```

   Interesting reading: [Why is printf better than
   echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)